# LaTeX hungs on EPS processing

Tags: eps, combine

The pdflatex.exe process hungs.
I have two TeX files, FIRST imports SECOND (by using combine class). SECOND file has `\includegraphics{DDS_images_eps/SIN_0.eps}`, and compiles fine. But FIRST hungs. In FIRST file I commented all unnecessary fields.
Ending of FIRST file Log is

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <DDS_images_eps/SIN_0.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-04-24 06:05:44
(epstopdf)                    size: 130169 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <DDS_images_eps/SIN_0-eps-converted-to.pdf>    
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-10-31 15:46:56
(epstopdf)                    size: 8670 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=DDS_images_eps/SIN_0-eps-converted-to.pdf DDS_images_eps/SIN_0.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 479.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.

<DDS_images_eps/SIN_0-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=94, 676.5275pt x 126.4725pt>
File: DDS_images_eps/SIN_0-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)    
<use DDS_images_eps/SIN_0-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: DDS_images_eps/SIN_0-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 479.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 155.99762pt x 29.16139pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <DDS_images_e
```

What's the problem?

UPDATE:MWE

SECOND file

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
     \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{SIN_1800.pdf}
     \caption{Ground state}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

FIRST file

```
\documentclass[report,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{combine} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{papers}
    \import{MWE_child}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

MWE work if I disable `subfig` package or `\caption{..}`. But I can't disable it. Rest of the file can use it.

Nevertheless, when I compile SECOND file(with uncomment packages) it work fine.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: The protocol only shows a successful graphics inclusion. Try to make a MWE or at least try to identify the problematic source code lines, e.g. by moving `\end{document}` around, or adding `\show\x` or `\typeout{...}` as debugging helpers.

Comment: I tested a little, when I add `\caption{sometext}` between `\begin{figure}[!h]` and `\end{figure}` it doesn't work, but if I remove `\caption` all work fine. What is wrong?

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem, so I just replaced `\usepackage{subfig}` commands by `\usepackage{caption}`, `\usepackage{subcaption}`commands. It works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for `pdflatex` to use `eps` files. You can convert them using the `ps2pdf` command from the ghostscript package and then include the PDFs.

Comment: I use `epstopdf` package. So if pdf file doesn't exist, `epstopdf` build it(i compile SECOND file), but in case with FIRST file latex hungs.

Comment: the `epstopdf` package requires the shell-escape feature; have you enabled that?

Comment: Hmm, I disabled `epstopdf` and included pdf files(in SECOND file). But FIRST file doesn't compile.

Comment: @wasteofspace `epstopdf` doesn't need `--shell-escape`, for TeX Live 2011 or later and, I believe, with MiKTeX 2.9